# Script environment affects parent shell

Tags: powershell

Modifying certain aspects in PowerShell scripts seem to modify the running shell. This would be expected if I source the script instead of running it.

script.ps1

```bsh
[cultureinfo]::currentculture = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
```

```
> [cultureinfo]::currentculture

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1031             de-DE            Deutsch (Deutschland)

> .\script.ps1
> [cultureinfo]::currentculture
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> [cultureinfo]::currentculture

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
127                               Unveränderliche Sprache (Unveränderliches Land bzw. unveränderliche Region)
```

So obviously debug tracing is active and cultural change persisted...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) for `[cultureinfo]::currentculture]` (emphasis added):

> Gets or sets the CultureInfo object that represents the culture **used by the current thread**.

That is, a change by design takes effect for the entire thread, not just your script, and it persists throughout the thread's lifetime (after your script exits) or until you change it again.

Therefore, if you want your culture changes to be *scoped*, you must *manually*:

- save the previously current culture beforehand
- restore that culture afterwards.

**Caveat**:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, the culture is automatically reset to the *startup value*, but only *at the command prompt*, after every invocation of a command or script - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62938809/45375) for background information and a workaround; by contrast, if one script calls another and the callee changes the current culture, that change stays in effect for the calling script.
- By contrast, PowerShell *Core* behaves consistently, and never resets the current culture automatically.

---

Note that the behavior is similar to using `Set-Location` (`cd`) to change the current location (directory), which also affects the entire thread, as it does in a `cmd.exe` batch file (except if you use `setlocal`) - but *not* in a Bash script, for instance.

**In PowerShell, script files (`*.ps1`) run *in-process***, as do batch files (`*.cmd`, `*.bat`) in `cmd.exe`, whereas POSIX-like shells such as Bash run scripts in a *child process*, which implicitly and invariably scopes environment changes to such scripts.

Comment: As for your last paragraph, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62932372/powershell-flexibility-in-scope-of-environment-variables-via-scripts