# Temporarily change powershell language to English?

Tags: powershell

I wrote some software that uses the output of system (powershell) commands, but did not foresee that the output would be different for languages other than English.

Is there a way to temporarily change the language in Powershell to English *for just that one, single powershell session*?

#### Notes

- In case it is of significance, the particular powershell code I wish to run is `netstat -n -a`
- I have come across some ways to change powershell language (e.g. [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/6ed8f2d9-082a-4c86-8066-e9b2391f5dff/how-to-change-language-in-powershell-to-english?forum=winserverpowershell), [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/560456-how-to-change-powershell-script-errors-to-english)). But I want to be careful not to change it permanently! (that would be bad)

Comment: `netstat` is not a powershell cmdlet - it's an executable. Why not use `Get-NetTCPConnection` in a powershell script instead?

Comment: It currently is not possible to change the language used in Powerahell

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- (a) **For *external programs* such as `netstat.exe`, there is unfortunately *no* way (that I know of) to change the UI language *in-session***:

  - On Windows Server 2012 / Windows 8 and above, the **[`Set-WinUILanguageOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuilanguageoverride) cmdlet** allows you to (persistently) **change the system-wide UI language for the current user**, but that only takes effect in *future* logon sessions - that is, **logging off and back on or a reboot are required**.
  - As an aside: On Windows Server 2012 / Windows 8 and above, there is also the **[`Set-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-culture)** cmdlet, but its **purpose is *not* to change the *UI* culture (display language)**, but only culture-specific **settings such as date, number, and currency formats**. It too changes the setting *persistently* for the current user, but only requires a new *session* (process) for the change to take effect.
- (b) **For *PowerShell commands* and *.NET types*, there *is* an in-session (non-persistent) solution** - assuming the commands are culture-aware and come with *localized strings* - see **important caveats further below**:

  - Set [`[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture) (temporarily) to the desired culture name (use [`[cultureinfo]::GetCultures('SpecificCultures')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures) to see all predefined ones) ; e.g.,  `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'`

    - Complementarily, you may want to set [`[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) (note the missing `UI` part) as well, which determines the culture-specific number, date, ... formatting.
    - In older versions of PowerShell / .NET, you'll have to set these properties on [`[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread) instead; e.g.,
      `[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'`
  - See the **bottom section** for **helper function `Use-Culture`** that wraps this functionality for execution of code with a different culture temporarily in effect; here's an example call
    with the culture-sensitive [`Get-LocalGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localgroupmember) cmdlet:

    ```bash
    # Try with values other than "en-US", e.g. "fr-FR" to see localized
    # values in the "ObjectClass" output column.
    Use-Culture en-US { Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators }
    ```
  - An **ad hoc example**, if you don't want to define a helper function (only the UI culture is changed here):

    ```bash
    & {
      $prev=[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture
      [cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture='en-US'
      Get-LocalGroupMember Administrators
      [cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture=$prev
    }
    ```

**Caveats**:

- Fundamentally, the above **only works with UI cultures corresponding to Windows languages actually installed for the current user**, as reflected in the output from [`Get-WinUserLanguageList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/get-winuserlanguagelist?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
- **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) itself is *not* localized yet, as of v7.4.x**; progress is being tracked in [GitHub issue #666](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/666); however, the solution above does work with third-party modules that ship with localized messages and help content, as well as select Windows-specific modules that talk to platform APIs, such as the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/) module, whose `Get-LocalGroupMember` cmdlet was used in the example above.
- **[*.NET (Core)*](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/)**, the cross-platform successor to the legacy, Windows-only *.NET Framework* seemingly does **NOT offer localized exception messages for its *built-in class library*** - though third-party libraries *may* offer them, if [explicitly implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-localized-exception-messages).
- While **built-in *.NET Framework* APIs do respect an in-process UI culture change**, that **seemingly doesn't extend to *system* error messages surfaced via .NET exceptions**, i.e. the error messages associated with the error codes returned from *WinAPI* functions - they remain in the *persistently* configured language for the current user.
- Due to a **bug in *Windows PowerShell*** (PowerShell [Core] v6+ is *not* affected), **in-session changes to `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture` and `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` are *automatically reset* at the command prompt, whenever a command finishes executing**; however, for a given script the changes remain in effect for the entire script and its callees - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56922526/45375).

---

Taking a step back:

> I wrote some software that uses the output of system (powershell) commands, but did not foresee that the output would be different for languages other than English.

This is precisely why **it's generally worth looking for *PowerShell-native* solutions as opposed to calling *external programs***:

**Instead of having to parse - possibly localized - *text*, as with `netstat.exe`, for instance, PowerShell commands return *objects* whose properties you can robustly access in a culture-independent fashion.**

Specifically, [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) suggests looking at [`Get-NetTCPConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection) as a PowerShell alternative to `netstat.exe` (available on Windows Server 2012 / Windows 8 and above).

---

#### Function `Use-Culture`'s source code:

Note: The code was gratefully adapted from [this venerable blog post](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/windows-powershell-2-0-string-localization/); it is designed

```bash
# Runs a script block in the context of the specified culture, without changing 
# the session's culture persistently.
# Handy for quickly testing the behavior of a command in the context of a different culture.
# Example: 
#   Use-Culture fr-FR { Get-Date }
function Use-Culture
{    
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [cultureinfo] $Culture,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
  )
  # Note: In Windows 10, a culture-info object can be created from *any* string.
  #        However, an identifier that does't refer to a *predefined* culture is 
  #        reflected in .LCID containing 4096 (0x1000)
  if ($Culture.LCID -eq 4096) { Throw "Unrecognized culture: $($Culture.DisplayName)" }

  # Save the current culture / UI culture values.
  $PrevCultures = [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture

  try {
    # (Temporarily) set the culture and UI culture for the current thread.
    [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $Culture

    # Now invoke the given code.
    & $ScriptBlock

  }    
  finally {
    # Restore the previous culture / UI culture values.
    [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $PrevCultures[0]
    [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $PrevCultures[1]
  }
}
```

Comment: As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62909277/2707864), it appears that `[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread` is not session-scoped, but execution line-scoped.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: Please see my update under "Caveats".

Comment: Ok, then you might have a say in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62909277/powershell-scope-of-changes-in-lines-with-multiple-commands-uiculture

Comment: And you may know about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62909619/powrshell-uiculture-vs-windows-setting

Answer (score 3):

Original author of this code is @Scepticalist.

Run this from powershell console. It will change the culture to en-US for current session.

```
function Set-CultureWin([System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture) { [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture ; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture } ; Set-CultureWin en-US ; [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture
```

Then you have to use the command `Get-NetTCPConnection` Instead of netstat. For its usage see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. I will test as soon as I have access to a windows box. Do you know if the output of `Get-NetTCPConnection` is precisely the same as `netstat`?

Comment: Yes, the output of that cmdlet is even broad and helpful than netstat.