# How to change language of powershell script?

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

i have developed a project in WFP in which i launch a command via Powershell.exe, but i would like the return language of the script output to be English and not French, how can i do?

```
    private void myfunction()
        {
            Process myprocess= new Process();
            myprocess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                FileName = "Powershell.exe",
                Arguments = "netsh wlan show interface",
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            };
            process.Start();
            String mystring= process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```

I tried to use this, to change the language but nothing,the output remains in French

```
 CultureInfo newCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
```

Comment: This has relevant information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909992/temporarily-change-powershell-language-to-english

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work