# PowerShell scope of changes in lines with multiple commands - UICulture

Tags: powershell, scope, culture, currentculture, currentuiculture

During my tinkering with PS 5.1 related to the objective of question [Fully change language for the current PowerShell session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62872708/fully-change-language-for-the-current-powershell-session)
I observed a "strange" behavior:

```
> [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture ; [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentuiculture ;
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1033             en-US            English (United States)
1033             en-US            English (United States)
> function Set-CultureWin([System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture) { [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture ; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture } ; Set-CultureWin es-ES ; [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture ; [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentuiculture ;
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
3082             es-ES            Español (España)
3082             es-ES            Español (España)
> [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture ; [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentuiculture ;
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1033             en-US            English (United States)
1033             en-US            English (United States)
```

(the function above was obtained from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59910693/2707864)).
Replacing `[system.threading.thread]::currentthread.` with `[cultureinfo]::` everywhere produced exactly the same results.

What I found strange is:

1. I conclude that the boundary of a "thread" (the currentthread) appears to be the execution command line.

   Nevertheless, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59911341/2707864) it is quoted as "a session-scoped (non-persistent) solution" (in response to its OP [Temporarily change powershell language to English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909992/temporarily-change-powershell-language-to-english)).
   That answer even posted a wrapper function to limit the scope of the change to the executing command.

   This information apparently opposes [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118816/2707864), which states "`[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` only affects to current one-liner" (coinciding with my conclusion).
2. I can obtain an immediate change of `Culture` for just that one "thread", even if `Set-Culture` only takes effect after launching a new session.

   I might conclude that's how it works.

**How can these two points be rationalized?**
(I would welcome authoritative documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a ***bug* in *Windows PowerShell***<sup>[1]</sup> (PowerShell [Core] v6+ is *not* affected), **in-session changes to `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture` and `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` are *automatically reset* to the *values at startup time*<sup>[2]</sup> at the command prompt, whenever a command finishes executing**.

Trying to modify the culture(s) in `$PROFILE` is equally affected, unfortunately.

However, for a given script, *in-script* culture changes remain in effect for the entire script as well as its callees (on the main thread) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56922526/45375).

There are two possible **workarounds**:

- **Use reflection to modify the non-public field where Windows PowerShell stores the start-up culture value(s)** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118816/45375).

  - Note: Modifying non-public fields is generally ill-advised, but should be fine in this case, given that Windows PowerShell will see no new development; however, note that `$PSUICulture` / `$PSCulture` will *not* reflect the culture put into effect by the workaround - use `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` / `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture` instead.
- Alternatively, **change the current user's *OS-level* language / locale settings *before* starting PowerShell**:

  - Programmatically,

    - you can change the current user's **display language** (**UI culture**, reflected in `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture`) with [`Set-WinUILanguageOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuilanguageoverride)
    - you can change the **locale** (**culture**, reflected in `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`) with [`Set-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-culture)
    - Note that both commands require at least Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 R2 and that `Set-WinUILanguageOverride` requires a logoff of reboot to take effect, while `Set-Culture` changes only take effect in *future* sessions (but don't require a logoff / reboot).

---

<sup>[1] There is no official bug report I am aware of, but the following factors lead me to classify Windows PowerShell's behavior as a *bug*: The behavior is counterintuitive, cannot be avoided other than via [a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118816/45375), and has been corrected in PowerShell [Core] v6+. Also, a core member of the PowerShell team had this to say in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4545#issuecomment-321656251): "I forget exact details, but the current culture is reset for reasons I never understood."</sup>

<sup>[2] The values at startup of the *PowerShell* process, as determined by the user's OS-level display language and locale settings (regional format).</sup>