# PowerShell flexibility in scope of environment variables via scripts

Tags: bash, powershell, variables, scope, environment-variables

In bash, if I define a variable inside a script (say, `set_var.sh`), I can choose whether those definitions persist after "running" the script.
This will depend on how I "run" the script, the options being:

1. `sh set_var.sh` (variables do not persist)
2. `./set_var.sh` (variables do not persist, same as point 1)
3. `source set_var.sh` (variables persist)

This is irrespective from the variable being exported to the environment or not in  `set_var.sh`.

**Can the same as items 1 and 3 above be achieved with PowerShell 5.1 scripts, for both PS and `$env` variables?**

For an illustration see (1) below.

---

**EDIT**:

As per answer by Mathias R. Jessen, the equivalent to item #3 above is "dot sourcing".
There is also an "intermediate" case (not identified above, perhaps there is also a way to get this in bash), where environment variables persist but PS variables don't.

My script:

```
# set_var.ps1
$env:TEST_VAR = 'test_var'
$TEST_VAR2 = 'test_var2'
```

What I checked:

```
> $env:TEST_VAR ; $TEST_VAR2 ;
> . .\set_var.ps1
> $env:TEST_VAR ; $TEST_VAR2 ;
test_var
test_var2
> Remove-Variable TEST_VAR2 ; Remove-Item env:TEST_VAR ;
> $env:TEST_VAR ; $TEST_VAR2 ;
> .\set_var.ps1
> $env:TEST_VAR ; $TEST_VAR2 ;
test_var
> Remove-Item env:TEST_VAR ;
> $env:TEST_VAR ; $TEST_VAR2 ;
> & .\set_var.ps1
> $env:TEST_VAR ; $TEST_VAR2 ;
test_var
```

---

(1) **Example of persistent / non-persistent variables**

I have script `set_var.sh` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

export TEST_VAR=test_var
TEST_VAR2=test_var2
```

Then the following commands prove my point:

```
$ echo $TEST_VAR ; echo $TEST_VAR2


$ sh set_var.sh ; echo $TEST_VAR ; echo $TEST_VAR2


$ source set_var.sh ; echo $TEST_VAR ; echo $TEST_VAR2
test_var
test_var2
$ echo $TEST_VAR ; echo $TEST_VAR2
test_var
test_var2
$ env | grep TEST_VAR
TEST_VAR=test_var
$ unset TEST_VAR ; unset TEST_VAR2
$ echo $TEST_VAR ; echo $TEST_VAR2


$ ./set_var.sh ; echo $TEST_VAR ; echo $TEST_VAR2


$ echo $TEST_VAR ; echo $TEST_VAR2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62936160/45375):

Regarding your edit:

It is a script's **direct invocation / invocation via `&`** - which, unlike in `sh` / `bash`, runs *in-process* - **preserves changes to *environment variables*, but not to *regular* variables in the script.**<sup>[1]</sup>

A succinct demonstration, using `&` with a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) in lieu of a script file:

```
PS> & { $foo = 'bar'; $env:foo = 'bar-env' }; "[$foo]", "[$env:foo]"
[]        # regular variable in the script [block] scope went out of scope
[bar-env] # environment variable is visible to caller (the whole *process*)
```

---

As for the PowerShell equivalent of 1. (`sh set_var.sh`)
and 2. (`./set_var.sh`):

**An explicit call to the PowerShell CLI**  ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1) in Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) in PowerShell [Core], v6+): **is needed to run a script in a *child process***.

Note: The following examples use `pwsh`, but the same applies to `powershell.exe` (whose CLI is a mostly identical to `pwsh`'s, with only a few parameters having been added to the latter).

In the simplest case, use `-File` (which is the implied parameter in PowerShell [Core], but is required in Windows PowerShell):

```
pwsh -File set_var.ps1  # PowerShell v6+: same as: pwsh set_var.ps1
```

Note, however, that **you'll only get *textual* output (strings)** from the script this way rather than the rich *objects* that PowerShell normally supports.

The **simplest way to receive *objects* instead** - available from *inside* PowerShell only<sup>[2]</sup> - is to **pass a *script block*** in which the script is called instead, which automatically makes the CLI output XML-serialized representations of the script's output objects, and causes these representations to be automatically deserialized by the calling session:

```
pwsh { .\set_var.ps1 }
```

Note:

- The `.\` prefix is necessary, because PowerShell - by design, as a security feature - does not permit running scripts by *mere file name* from the *current directory*.
- The XML-based serialization using the CLIXML format - which is also used for PowerShell's remoting and background jobs - **has limits with respect to *type fidelity***; except for .NET primitive types and a handful well-known types, you get `[pscustomobject]`-based *approximations* of the original objects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).

---

<sup>[1] However, PowerShell does offer the ability to set variables across in-session scope boundaries, e.g. `$global:foo = 'bar'` to set a session-global variable or `Set-Variable foo bar -Scope 1` to set a variable in the *caller's* (parent) scope (which when called from a script's top-level scope would also be the global scope).</sup>

<sup>[2] From outside of PowerShell, you can explicitly request output in CLIXML format (the XML-based object-serialization format), namely with the `-of Xml` CLI parameter, but you'll have to parse the XML yourself and reconstruct objects from it.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You want `.` - the [*dot-sourcing* operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) - which executes your script or command in the caller's scope, thereby persisting all variables after execution:

```bsh
# set_vars.ps1
$TEST_VAR = 123
```

```bsh
# script.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot/set_vars.ps1
echo $TEST_VAR # outputs 123
```

To *avoid* locally defined variables persisting after execution, either execute the script as-is, or by explicitly using the `&` invocation operator:

```
# script.ps1
& $PSScriptRoot/set_vars.ps1
echo $TEST_VAR 
# outputs an empty string, assuming $TEST_VAR was not already defined in the callers scope
```

Comment: This is the equivalent to my item #3 (persistent variables). What would the equivalent to #1 be?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio that would just be the default behavior when executing a script (with or without the `&` operator)

Comment: Please see EDIT of OP. The default behavior (with or without &) is an intermediate case, not #1.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio What do you mean by that? `&` or simply running it with `.\` runs in the *script* scope, a special scope for scripts in PowerShell which localizes the variables in the script. If you want like "local local" you can try dotsourcig inside of an `&` to make it available inside the `&` which is local like `& {. "Path\To\File"}`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7